# Scrollbars does not display in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

It is installed the latest version of Firefox 3.6.3 on 2 machines. Both machines runs under Windows 7, but one is 32 bit version, another is 64 bit. The 64 bit machine does not display scrollbars on [my website](http://www.amiproject.com/templates/HomeMove).
32 bit machine and machines under Windows XP does not have that problem. I have googled but have not find such issue. Could you please let me know how at least I should investigate that?

Scrollbars emulated by 2 divs. One nested into another. Nested div is higher then external, so external div displays a scrollbar.

Comment: Works fine in my Firefox 3.6.3 (Ubuntu Lucid 64bit). Could you post some screenshots to describe the problem or code samples that  do not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look furter to find differences between the machines. It's most likely not a problem of having a 32 vs. a 64 bit version of Windows.

I have 64 bit Windows 7 and I tried your site in Firefox 3.6.3, and the scrollbars appear just fine.

Firefox is a 32 bit application, so it will run in 32 bit mode (WOW) on a 64 bit system.

Comment: The language setting are the same. I have no idea what to look further. I appreciate any ideas

Comment: +1, me too: `I have 64 bit Windows 7 and I tried your site in Firefox 3.6.3, and the scrollbars appear just fine.`